# Matching a string which includes -,.$\/ with a regex

Tags: sql, regex, oracle11g

I am trying to match a  string which includes -,.$/ ( and might include other special characters which I don't know yet(  with a regex . I have to match first 28 characters in the string

The String is -->

`Received - Data Migration 1. Units, of UNITED STATES $ CXXX CORPORATION COMMON SHARE STOCK CERTIFICATE NO. 323248 987,837 SHARES PAR VAL $1.00 NOT ADMINISTERED XX XX, XXXSFHIGSKF/XXXX PURPOSES ONLY`

The regex I am using is `((([\w-,.$\/]+)\s){28}).*`

Is there a better way to match special characters ?

Also I get an error if the string length is less than 28. What can I do to include the range so that the regex works even if the string is less than 28 characters

the code looks something like this

```
Select  regexp_extract(Txn_Desc,'((([\w-,.$;!@\/%)^#<>&*(]+)\s){1,28}).*',1) as Transaction_Short_Desc,Txn_Desc
from Table x
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I am trying to match a string".... "I have to match first 28 characters in the string"? I have a suspicion that standard string functions and operators (SUBSTR, LIKE) - rather than regular expressions - may help, but it is not clear what the problem is in the first place.

Comment: regexp_extract as shown above has helped me get the desired results. However, is there a better of matching the regex pattern for special characters different than what I have shown in the code above

Comment: I don't understand. There is no `regexp_extract` in Oracle. Are you shure you are using Oracle (as your tabs show) and not something else? Also, you should be able to express a requirement in common language (not using code) - don't make the reader try to guess what the code was meant to do, just tell them what your requirement is.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are looking for 28 tokens.

Try

```
(\S+\s+){0,28}
```

or

```
([^ ]+ +){0,28}
```

---

This is the result for 8 tokens:

```
Received - Data Migration 1. Units, of UNITED 
|        | |    |         |  |      |  |
1        2 3    4         5  6      7  8
```